# CSS: Absolute positioning for fixed width?

Tags: css

I am thinking about relative vs absolute positioning in CSS. Is there actually any point in using relative positioning if you have a fixed-width layout?

Philip

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: well this is my question what the dependencies are ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the fixed width body to be put in the center of the screen? Do you want it just 5px to the right? It does depend and it is all dependent on what you want to achieve with your site.

Comment: Ok so your saying that with absolute width you lose flexiblity

Comment: No, I am saying that the use of relative positioning or absolute positioning is dependent on what you are trying to achieve. As I stated, you may want to center the the fixed-width object or you may not. I typically would center a fixed width object but that is just me.

Comment: So you would use relative positioning in that instance. Use `margin: 0 auto;` on whatever you are centering.